# Struggling to read excel data in Spyder IDE using pandas code

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a .xlsx file in Spyder (Python 3.8) using pandas code but the code would not read the excel file. I have tried saving the excel file in the same folder where the code is saved and have also installed "openpyxl" as well. I dont understand why the data could not be read. Appreciate any solution please.

**code input:**

import pandas as pd

orders = pd.read_excel("Hotel Industry - Orders Database - 2019.xlsx", sheet_name="Order Database")

**error:**

orders = pd.read_excel("Hotel Industry - Orders Database - 2019.xlsx", sheet_name="Order Database")
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\19001090\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17828/2548343590.py", line 1, in 
orders = pd.read_excel("Hotel Industry - Orders Database - 2019.xlsx", sheet_name="Order Database")

File "C:\Users\19001090\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\19001090\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_base.py", line 364, in read_excel
io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)

File "C:\Users\19001090\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_base.py", line 1191, in **init**
ext = inspect_excel_format(

File "C:\Users\19001090\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_base.py", line 1070, in inspect_excel_format
with get_handle(

File "C:\Users\19001090\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 711, in get_handle
handle = open(handle, ioargs.mode)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Hotel Industry - Orders Database - 2019.xlsx'

Comment: Your error message  is clear: *FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Hotel Industry - Orders Database - 2019.xlsx'.* Your call to `pd.read_excel()`does not provide a path and so Python looks in what it thinks is the current working directory. That is not what most novices expect. Provide a full path in the call, and remember to use a raw string `r"path\to\Hotel Industry - Orders Database - 2019.xlsx"`.

Comment: @BoarGules :Thank you but I have tried providing the full path and still gives me the below error:
ImportError: 
Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'.  Use pip or conda to install openpyxl.

Not sure if this is due to the Cloud or am I supposed to save the excel files and scripts in the installation folder instead of desktop

I have installed 'openpyxl' as well "conda install -c anaconda openpyxl" through Anaconda Prompt

Comment: @BoarGules, please see the code below, not sure what I am doing wrong..
orders = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\19001090\OneDrive - Newmont USA Limited\Desktop\Python\Hotel Industry - Orders Database - 2019.xlsx", sheet_name="Order Database")


  File "C:\Users\19001090\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\_optional.py", line 118, in import_optional_dependency
    raise ImportError(msg) from None

ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'.  Use pip or conda to install openpyxl.

Comment: That is a different question. And the error message is equally clear, and has nothing to do with the location of your data. It says *use `pip` or `conda` to install `openpyxl`*. Did you follow that advice? If you did, and you get the *same* error, try looking for a question about `pandas` and `openpyxl`.

Comment: @BoarGules, thanks for advising. Yes I have followed the instructions, in fact tried everything from the last two days to get SPyder read excel data, but unfortunately no luck so far. Thanks for looking into this, I will try more on pandas and openpyxl to see if I am missing anything.